# How to detect that a sprite has encountered a color in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want to detect that the sprite has encountered a color in pygame, which function should I use to achieve this function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post examples of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Can you please add more detail to the reasons behind your question.  Perhaps there's a better solution than colour-picking.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is possible to get the color at any point in the surface that you want to check against using `get_at()` (docs [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at)). You would need to find the new area that your sprite covered that it did not cover last time and check every pixel in that, and if other things were moving around you would have to check if your sprite now overlapped with any of those area and check that. Or you could decide that was too complicated and just run through every pixel under your sprites location (without you sprite drawn yet) and check for that color.

It is possible, but would likely not be very fast.

An alternative is if you know where those colors are you can mark those areas using rects, circles, sprites or masks (see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) and [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask)) that you can check against. That is usually much faster. These do not have to be drawn and so would be invisible. They would just be used to mark areas for the collision check.

If you do not know exactly where the colors are in the background or the other images, you can create masks based on the colors in them using `pygame.mask.from_surface()` or `pygame.mask.from_threshold()` (docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface) and [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_threshold)).

Comment: The background-colour mask is an interesting idea.  I guess the OP could use multiple masks for multiple colours.

Comment: @Kingsley Yes you could certainly create/extract multiple masks for different colors or color ranges (with threshold). You could even extract multple color sets and and combine them into a single mask. If you had multiple it might be better to combine them and do one mask check (rather than multiple mask checks) and then do a more refined mash check if there was a collision (assuming that the collisions are the more rare event than not colliding), but I'm not certain of that.